# Eclipselink in clause

Tags: java, sql, jpa, eclipselink

I'm trying to use a in clause with eclipselink JPA, but nothing is working

```
final String parameterizedQuery = "Select * FROM sap.Preco WHERE cliente_id = ?clienteId and numero_material in ( ?numeroMaterial )";
listPreco = em.createNativeQuery(parameterizedQuery)
                .setParameter("clienteId", clienteId).setParameter("numeroMaterial", produtoId)
                .getResultList();
```

produtoId id is a String with comma separated values

```
String produtoId = StringUtils.join(listMaterial, "','");
```

or

```
String produtoId = StringUtils.join(listMaterial, ",");
```

both does not work, this is the log:

> Select
>   * FROM sap.Preco WHERE cliente_id = ? and numero_material in ( ? )    bind => [0000006775, 000000000000100003,000000000000100003]

Already tried to use a list as parameter but does not work.

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can not infer an SQL type to be used for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with a specific value type to specify the type to be used.

Comment: Why are you using a native SQL query instead of JPQL?  This is supported in JPQL, which will break the list up and add each item to the generated SQL, but for a native SQL query, you must add each item individually yourself. Or add it to the SQL statement inline, but this opens you up to SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a comma separated string and JDBC does not support IN with a parameter

Read more about the options you have:
https://javachannel.org/posts/using-sqls-in-in-jdbc/

Comment: List is not supported by postgres.

Comment: But you are using JPA. this will take care of it. so setParameter does some magic behind the scence

Comment: Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can not infer an SQL type to be used for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with a specific value type to specify the type to be used.

Comment: Difference is JPQL supports this, SQL does not.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the parenthesis surrounding the named parameter:

```
final String parameterizedQuery = "Select * FROM sap.Preco WHERE cliente_id = ?clienteId and numero_material in  ?numeroMaterial ";
```

and pass the string list as parameter:

```
em.setParameter("numeroMaterial", listMaterial);
```

Comment: Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Can not infer an SQL type to be used for an instance of java.util.ArrayList. Use setObject() with a specific value type to specify the type to be used.